# Database File Location for SQLite within MonoDroid

Tags: android, xamarin.android

When using the following code to copy a SQLite database from an Assets folder , the output is being put in the following folder:
**"/data/data/AndroidTestDb.AndroidTestDb/files/AndroidTestDup.db"**

Here is the code:

```
Stream myInput = Assets.Open(@"AndroidTest.db");

string outFileName=System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath 
(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "AndroidTestDup.db");

Stream myOutput = new FileStream(outFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
```

And the desired folder +filename is :

**"/data/data/AndroidTestDb.AndroidTestDb/databases/AndroidTestDup.db"**

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct way, the closest I can think of is:

```
// someContext may be the current activity
String outFileName = someContext.getFilesDir().getParent().getAbsolutePath() + "/databases/AndroidTestDup.db";
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [Context.GetDatabasePath](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)) to obtain the filesystem path for your database file:

```
// Assuming a Context subclass, e.g. an Activity
string dbPath = GetDatabasePath("AndroidTestDup.db").AbsolutePath;
```

Answer (score 0):

My idea to find out the sqlite database in monodroid is,

- -First Install any android File Explorer application in your
  emulator.
- -Then using the application just select any location you want to store your database.
- -Then Use "adb push  " command in adb. to copy your source
  database to a mobile location that
  you have selected.
- -So now you know path of the database.
- -Just use that path in your program.

Thank you...