# Binding button path image (Using MvxBaseAndroidTargetBinding) Android

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

How to binding path image to button, using MvxBaseAndroidTargetBinding?

1) I Create a binding

```
public class MvxButtonIconBinding: MvxBaseAndroidTargetBinding
{
    private readonly View _view;

public MvxButtonIconBinding(View view)
{
    _view = view;
}

public override void SetValue(object value)
{
    string path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    path = Path.Combine(path, "pictures");
    path = Path.Combine(path, (string)value);
    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        var dr = Drawable.CreateFromPath(path);
        Button b = _view as Button;
        var drawables = b.GetCompoundDrawables();
        foreach (var d in drawables)
            if (d!=null)
                d.Dispose(); // To avoid "out of memory" messages
        b.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, dr, null, null);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File {0} does not exists", path);
    } 
}

public override MvxBindingMode DefaultMode
{
    get { return MvxBindingMode.OneWay; }
}

public override Type TargetType
{
    get { return typeof(string); }
}

protected override void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
{
    if (isDisposing)
    {
    }
    base.Dispose(isDisposing);
}
```

}

2) Setup the binding :

```
registry.RegisterFactory(new MvxCustomBindingFactory<View>("ButtonIcon", view => new MvxButtonIconBinding(view)));
```

3) Create button_list.аxml

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/ButtonArticle"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="160dp"
android:gravity="bottom|center"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
local:MvxBind="{'Click':{'Path':'Command1'},'ButtonIcon':{'Path':'Item.PictureFileName'}}"
android:textSize="14dip"
android:textColor="@drawable/ToggleButtonSelector" />
```

---

**Which path transmit properties PictureFileName? Show me an example please.**

---

[*Taken from*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12914544/ssue-with-binding-to-gridlayout-to-android)

Answer (score 0):

From your code, the image should be in:

```
string path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
path = Path.Combine(path, "pictures");
path = Path.Combine(path, (string)value);
```

So if your input value `Item.PictureFileName` is 'icon1.png' then you need to have an image saved in:

```
/data/data/YOUR_APP_NAME/files/pictures/icon1.png
```

---

I worked this out according to the info on `System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal` in [Database File Location for SQLite within MonoDroid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319666/database-file-location-for-sqlite-within-monodroid)

---

If you are using a fixed icon set (not downloading or dynamically creating images), then you might be better off using a resourceId approach like that shown in `SetButtonBackground` in [the conference sample](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/vnext/Sample%20-%20CirriousConference/Cirrious.Conference.UI.Droid/Bindings/FavoritesButtonBinding.cs)

Comment: If this explanation doesn't work, then it might be an idea to post a sample project - e.g. to a repository on GitHub. Others might be able to help debug your sample project - but they might not have time to write a sample project to assist.

Comment: I think can be used FavoritesButtonBinding. But I do not know how to return ID relative to that name pictures

Comment: Sorry - I don't think I can help at this question level - I often don't understand what you ask. Maybe try building at test project and posting it on Github - we can both speak code :)